# $\emptyset , \{0\}, \{\emptyset \}, 0$ differences

Tags: real-analysis

Given are:
$\emptyset , \{0\}, \{\emptyset \}, 0$.

Explain the differences.

Now, in the solution there is just:

0 is the number zero.
$\emptyset$ is the empty set.
ect.

But that isn't very explaining imo.

What would be common mistakes when dealing with those.

And is there a "real" difference between $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ ?

Comment: It has a bit of ambiguity when you write $0$. However, $\emptyset$ is clearly different from $\{\emptyset\}$. For the reason, consider the number of elements in the sets.

Comment: Ofc $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are different. The first one is the emptyset, i.e. the set with no elements. The second is a singleton, i.e. a set with an element (the emptyset).

Comment: We literally had the same question asked earlier today. You may want to consider searching for duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\emptyset$ is shorthand for the set $\{\}$, which is known as the empty set (the set with no elements in it).

$\{0\}$ is the set containing $0$, where $0$ typically denotes either the familiar real number, or an analogous element of some other structure (e.g. zero-vector of vector space, identity of group (in additive notation, common in ring and field theory).

$\{\emptyset\}$ is the set containing the empty set, which is a nonempty set. In some versions of the set-theoretic construction of the natural numbers, this corresponds to $1$, and the set containing $0$, $\{ 0\}$.

$0$ was already described above when I talked about $\{ 0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\emptyset$ is the set containing nothing; i.e., $\emptyset = \{\}$.

$\{\emptyset\}$ is the set that has just one element, namely $\emptyset$. So, $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set of sets.

$0$ is the number zero.

$\{0\}$ is the set containing just one element, namely $0$. Unlike $\{\emptyset\}$, $\{0\}$ is not a set of sets. It is a set of numbers.

Comment: "is not a set of sets. It is a set of numbers." that difference is one i looked for, thanks.

Comment: That's unfortunately imprecise. In modern mathematics, almost everything is defined as a set, including the number $0$. In fact, the ordinal number $0$ is defined exactly as the empty set.

Comment: Yes, I know. But given the op level, I didn't see the point of mentioning that in my answer.

Comment: @Qiyu Numbers are not sets; they're numbers. For some purposes, however, it can be convenient to code numbers as sets. Let's not fool ourselves into thinking, e.g., Fermat didn't *really* know what the number 2 was!