# Are set notations $\emptyset $ and $\{\emptyset\}$ Different?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question** : Let $A_0=\emptyset $ (the empty set).For each $i=1,2,3,...,$ define the set -

$A_i=A_{i-1}$ $\cup$ {$A_{i-1}$}. The set $A_3$ is :

- $\emptyset $
- $\{\emptyset\}$
- $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$
- $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}$

**My Work** : I Googled this, but didn't get anything useful.

Comment: Yes they are different. $\{ \emptyset \}$ is a singleton set and $\emptyset$ is null set.

Comment: Set $\{\varnothing\}$ has an element: $\varnothing$. Set $\varnothing$ has **no** elements (another notation for this set is $\{\}$). So the sets are different.

Comment: I am curious, **how** have you googled that? As for your question, think about sets as boxes. Is an empty box different from a box containing an empty box?

Comment: @user251257 I meant looked Wiki of null set etc.

Comment: One of infinitely many: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951267/why-is-emptyset-not-emptyset/1951388; another would be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845389/emptyset-0-emptyset-0-differences/1845392

Comment: So, answer should be last option, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the set $A_n$ has $n$ elements; it's the standard representative of the ordinal number $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\emptyset \subset \emptyset$ but $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$ (and also $\emptyset \subset \{\emptyset \}$ since $\emptyset $ is included in every set.)

Now $$\{\emptyset \}\in \{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset \}\}\quad \text{and}\quad \{\emptyset \}\subset \{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset \}\}.$$

Comment: That last example is amusing. A set is an element as well as a subset of another set. +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're different.

$\emptyset$ denotes a set with no elements (null set) whereas $\{\emptyset\}$ denotes a set with 1 element, namely, the empty set being the element of this set.

Therefore, $A_i \neq A_j$ $\forall i \neq j$

Also, observe that, $|A_i| = i$ $\forall i \in \mathbb{Z}$